# What is the most durable electronic pipette?

Tags: lab-techniques, cell-culture

We have a routine task of pipetting substance concentration series in triplicate on cell cultures under a laminar hood. To speed up the process, we use an electronic pipette in the repetitive pipetting mode and an electronic dispenser. The pipettes are several times a day wiped with 70% ethanol for decontamination, as they are moved to and from the hood. Up to date, we used the Eppendorf ones, but they fail after roughly a year of use. The failing parts are usually piston position sensor and pipette tip sensor on electronis dispenser.

Does anybody have an experience with the durability of different brands of electronic pipettes (Socorex Acura electro, Gilson Pipetman M, MT E4, maybe, others), especially under a laminar hood in repetitive pipetting mode?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What type of alcohol do you use? We used to wash plastic cuvettes with cheapest version of denatured alcohol. It had negative effect on properties of the plastic. Then one of our colleagues researched it and found that not the alcohol itself but the denaturing compound was the main culprit for deteriorating the plastic. Since then we switched to ethanol denatured with methanol.

Comment: We use 96% ethanol diluted to 70% with distilled water. I am not sure if the source ethanol contains any denaturating agent, but I will find out - thanks for the point @BagiM